# I have getting error when i'm using message.htmlView to send mail in adonis js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules, adonis.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhR3Z.png)

The error:

```
Error: "@adonisjs/view" must be installed before using "message.htmlView"
```

I have installed this package but still getting error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

After running the command `npm i @adonisjs/view`, the next thing to do is to configure the package before it can work and do to that you just run the command `node ace configure @adonisjs/view`.

For more information, check out https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/views/introduction#setup